# Format GWT Mobile ListPanel like a table

Tags: gwt, mobile, alignment, uibinder

I have the following code in my ui-binder.

```
<m:ListPanel selectable="false">
  <m:ListItem>  
    <g:Label ui:field="sortLabel"></g:Label>
    <m:DropDownList ui:field="sortDropDown" />
  </m:ListItem>
  <m:ListItem>
    <g:Label ui:field="doneLabel"></g:Label>
    <m:FlipSwitch ui:field="displayDone" value="false"/>
   </m:ListItem>
</m:ListPanel>
```

I want that the dropdownlist and the flipSwitch is in the same vertical alignment.
Currently is the flipSwitch a little bit too much on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `ListPanel` itself (which extends from `PanelBase`) does not support alignment. This was probably just an oversight. They used a `FlowPanel` which isn't capable of providing alignment without CSS hacks to change its structure.

In order to get them aligned, you could:

- Make your own `PanelBase` that *does* support alignment by using another type of panel in place of `FlowPanel _panel`, then make your own `ListPanel` which extends from your new `PanelBase`. Probably your best bet.

OR

- Use some CSS wizardry, something like (but probably not exactly) below. The trick is that `FlowPanel` uses a block layout style, and you need to make it something inline instead to support the `vertical-align` CSS property. This could have unforeseeable effects, so again you probably want the first route.

> ```
> .someStyle {
>     vertical-align:middle;
>     display:table-cell;
> }
> ```